# Memory issues with UIimagePickercontroller in iPhone

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Got to know that solving memory leaks manually, its not as easy as how ARC is taking care of releasing unwanted object in iOS,Thanks to Apple for introducing ARC, which makes job easy.
But i am one who stuck up with solving memory leaks manually,as i am working on pretty old code which is not using ARC. ok let me explain me the problem. My app contains code to capture picture in app. here is small piece of code which is doing this job.

```
- (void) takePhoto
{
    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"retain count of IPC is %d", [ipc retainCount]);
    ipc.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"retain count of IPC is %d", [ipc retainCount]);

    if(ipc) {   
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        NSLog(@"retain count of IPC is takephoto %d", [ipc retainCount]); 
        [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"retain count of IPC is %d", [ipc retainCount]);
    } else {
        VSCore *vsCore = [[VSCore alloc]init];
        [vsCore MessageBox:@"Device does not support taking photos"withTitle:kInfoEN];
        [vsCore release]; // written on april 14th 2013
    }
}
```

I am trying to track down the retain count of ipc object, so i had put NSlog at certain places. once i set the delegate,(ipc.delegate = self); delegates of UIImagePickercontroller will get called, one of them is

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{ }
```

after processing an image here, i am printing retain count of ipc, which is giving me result as 5, imagepickerdelegate is incrementing retaincount of ipc internally,but i have created the ipc object only once. according to this link http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-management-tutorial-video/ . number of release should be equal to retain count. if i call release more than once i am getting message sent to deallocated instance. but retain count of ipc   is still 5. can anyone help me out on this. thanks,

i am releasing Ipc in another class, i have declared ipc as a property in a single ton class, i am releasing ipc like this...

```
[[[VVideoDevice getInstance] ipc ] release];
```

ipc is a property in vvideodevice class.

Comment: Why can't you enable ARC? It will make all these problems go away and Xcode has a built in "Convert to ARC" menu option to make it easy.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the static analyzer? Instead of "Run" select "Analyze". This is good at spotting retain/release errors.

Comment: Will enabling ARC class wise would be effective? i will try that. but was wondering how retain count is incrementing automatically.

Comment: In the example code you have shown the retain count of ipc should only be 1. You have alloc/init-ed the class once so you should only have to release once. Where are you trying to release the ipc? Can you show the code that is giving you the release error? Also, have you used instruments to pin point where the memory leak is happening? Also, what is stopping you from converting to ARC? It is now recommended by Apple. The best approach is to commit your code to source control. Create a new branch and convert on the new branch. That way you can check it works (it will do) and merge later.

Comment: First of all don't use [retainCount].Because always it is giving unexpected result.Better you use static analyzer which will clearly show leaks.

Comment: when are you releasing ipc?

Comment: i am releasing ipc in another class, please look into last 2 lines, that i have edited.

Comment: If you can't or won't use `ARC` then simply use `ipc = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];`.

Comment: @frogmeister the absolute retainCount of the object is meaningless and making a claim of a particular value in that code is not useful.

Comment: @bbum you got my name wrong when it has an autocomplete? Ah, my mistake. The idea is still correct though. Either way, the static analyzer or ARC is where he needs to go.

Comment: @Fogmeister heh. Sorry about that. Slow connection.  Out typed the autocorrect and I like frogs.  Yes-- the rest of your advice is quite sound!

Comment: If you're releasing ipc in a singleton class, why are you allocating it every time when you takePhoto?

Answer (score 3):

retainCount is useless.  Do not call it.

That video about memory management is a horrible tutorial if it is instructing you that the absolute retain count of an object is meaningful.

You should balance your retains with release calls;  treat each retain as a +1 to the count and balance it with a release.

Use ARC.   Use the Allocations instrument to monitor memory use.   Finally,  use the static analyzer to help ensure your code is correct.

See http://www.whentouseretaincount.com for more information.

Comment: But the actual problem is that UIImagePickerController does leak. Even Apple's sample code for taking a picture leaks. It's a framework-level bug.